# QuickSand jQuery - want to modifications some options

Tags: jquery, css, gallery, quicksand

I'm using QuickSand right now, but i cant do some things.
I want to create small gallery with 3 categories, for example: All, Bus, Cars.
If I do it with QuickSand via default setting, it's problem, cos when I click some categorie all else image are hidden. I want to move focus image at a top of gallery, and else bottom ( NOT HIDING ).

I have a sample right there: [Sample](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html). especially I want to do that like on the site Sort by: Name, Size. But with my categories.
I trying do that, with no result :(

Maybe someone could help me.
Best cheers!

Comment: Anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jQuery [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) simply because the sorting function seems to be a little more advanced than what you're using. Quicksand seems to offer filtering pretty well, but the sorting function seems to be lacking a bit.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Y4mUN/16/)**

```
    getSortData: {
        symbol: function ($elem) {
            return $elem.attr('data-symbol');
        },
        category: function ($elem) {
            return $elem.attr('data-category');
        },
        number: function ($elem) {
            return parseInt($elem.find('.number').text(), 10);
        },
        weight: function ($elem) {
            return parseFloat($elem.find('.weight').text().replace(/[\(\)]/g, ''));
        },
        name: function ($elem) {
            return $elem.find('.name').text();
        },
        author: function ($elem) {
            return $elem.find('.author').text();
        },
        date: function ($elem) {
            return Date.parse($elem.find('.date').text());
        }
    }
});
```

With Isotope you can sort by pretty much any information that's present, and/or you can add a 'data-category' for even more sorting options.

[Isotope Sorting Demo](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/sorting.html)

[Isotope Sorting Documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html)

Note- Try resizing the browser window on the above demo or example.